# How to add variable to FormData in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually i am using following script to post my form

```
var formData = new FormData($("form#driver_information")[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/",
    data: formData, 
    success: function(data) {
    $("#page_message_box").html(data);
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

I need to pass some more variables along with form data

eg:

```
var formData = new FormData($("form#driver_information")[0]);
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/",
  data: formData + "&con=delete",  
  success: function(data) {
  $("#page_message_box").html(data);
 },
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
});
```

But it's not working.(  `data: formData + "&con=delete",` ). Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: `formData.append('varname', varname);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
formData.append('con', 'delete');
```

before the $.ajax call.

Then within that call you just need:

```
data: formData,
```

Comment: Thank you so much @rlarcombe

Answer (score 1):

You can append data to FormData like this:

```
formData.append('con', 'delete');
```